# Why am I getting a 400 response code?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am trying to get some acquaintance in using facebook API using Java (restfb). I am trying out the following code.

```
public class FBJava {

    private String API_Key = "xxxxxx";
    private String API_Secret = "xxxxxxxx";

    public String firstReq = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id="+API_Key+"&" +
            "redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html& scope=publish_stream,offline_access,create_event";
    public String secondReq = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="+API_Key+"" +
            "&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_secret="+API_Secret+"&code=";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FBJava fb = new FBJava();

        System.out.println(fb.firstReq);
        URL request = new URL(fb.firstReq);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) request.openConnection();
        conn.connect();

        int code = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(code);

    }
}
```

When I run the firstReq string in the browser manually, it is redirecting me to the correct page. But when I check the response code I am getting a 400 which means that its a bad request. I want to know why does it respond differently when I try to run it through the program. I know I am doing something wrong, but want to know what is the mistake and why is it occurring? Any kind of insight in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Is FBJava one of your own custom classes or is it part of a public API? If a public API, which one?

Comment: Yes its my own custom class...Not a part of any API

Comment: Oh, it must be the class from which this code comes?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include left over two lines, now its complete...Check the edited code now.

Comment: Is there a public API_Key and API_Secret that could be used in this SSCCE so we can reproduce and debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the `firstReq` url. It contains a whitespace character between "& scope". Try this (I just removed the whitespace):

```
  public String firstReq = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id="+API_Key+"&" +
    "redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,create_event";
```